# Вывод категорий с объектами в Django при помощи generic.ListView

Tags: django, listview, generics

Есть две связанные таблицы в базе, вот файлы

**models.py:**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    program = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.views import generic

class MovieListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Movie
    context_object_name = 'movie_list'
    now = timezone.now()
    queryset = Movie.objects.filter(start_datetime__gte=now).order_by('start_datetime')
    template_name = 'movie_list.html'
```

**base.html:**

```
{% for movie in movie_list %}
{{ movie.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Нужно вывести после названия категории, список всех фильмов этой категории, сохранив уже имеющийся фильтр и сортировку.

Как это делается классическим для Django способом?

Comment: Ты хочешь сделать вывод на этой странице, что бы был список всех категорий и за каждой категорией был список фильмов, или вывести на отдельную страницу информацию о каждой категории и ее списке фильмов?

Comment: список всех категорий и за каждой категорией был список фильмов

Comment: можно использовать `regroup` в шаблоне https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup